# how to get user confirmation status from AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I need getting an information about user confirmation status, using amazon-cognito-identity-js
Using this function i can't do it

```
export const getCognitoUser = (email) => {
    const userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: getUserPool()
    }
  return new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData)
}

export const getAuthDetails = (email, password) => {
  const authenticationData = {
    Username: email,
    Password: password,
   }
  return new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the backend api, one way is you can use adminGetUser method to get userStatus, more details here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html